# iPhone's accelerator refresh rate

Tags: ios, iphone, hardware

I wonder if it is possible to find the refresh rate for the iPhone's accelerator. Both for iPhone2G (with ios 3.1) and iPhone 4s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803180/169545

Minimum refresh rate is 10hz and maximum is 100hz.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the refresh rate using the `updateInterval` method on [UIAccelerometer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html)

> This property is measured in seconds. The value of this property is capped to certain minimum and maximum values. The maximum value is determined by the maximum frequency supported by the hardware. To ensure that it can deliver device orientation events in a timely fashion, the system determines the appropriate minimum value based on its needs.

Comment: i wanna know what's the "maximum frequency supported by the hardware" for iphone 2g and also iphone 4s.

Comment: you never said maximum :P it depends on a lot of things. The short answer is it will be as high as the iPhone can afford it to be. If you want an exact number, you can set the interval to a low number and log how often it updates. I would do this myself, but I have an iPhone 4 (not 4s) and it depends a lot on your environment.